# Append 'selected' to an option using JS (and possibly PHP)

Tags: javascript, html, select, append

I have a PHP page with:

```
<td class="short" id="inhouse-val<? echo $row['id'];?>"><? echo $row['inhouse'];?></td>
```

This table cell shows a user's selection of a drop down list called 'inhouse'. The options are 'Portland' and 'Remote'.

If a user clicks an Edit button, it fires a JS page with this:

```
document.getElementById("inhouse-val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='inhouse_text"+id+"' value='"+inhouse+"'>";
```

Obviously I will want to change `<input type...` to a Select list, however, the main thing I can't work out is how to have the JS file (or php) append 'selected' to the list option that is currently selected (inhouse) so that when this JS page stops executing and the returns to the PHP page, it shows the drop down list with the selected option as default.

For context, what happens is that the user is on the PHP page (which is an html table of rows from a database table) where a user can select a row and edit it. The JS file triggers and sets all the cells in the row to editable text fields. The user can then edit one, press Save and another PHP jumps in to overwrite those changes to the DB.

The problem I am having is that not all the table cells are text fields. 4 are selections from drop lists (like the example above).

My JS knowledge is weak but I can deal with PHP, so I am not sure how to script the example above so that it returns not a field with the current user text in it but rather it returns a drop list with the current user selection on it.

Here is the demo working page:
http://antistandard.com/projects/pathfinder/

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: So when you click 'Edit' you want to show those 4 `<select>` with a selected value from the DB instead of an `<input>`?

Comment: I'm watching you js code in the page you provided and i'll write a solution

Comment: Thank you @Gerardo

Comment: Try this

http://jsbin.com/neviduxecu/1/edit?js,output

Comment: let me know if it helped

Comment: @Gerardo Yeah.. you nailed it. Did you change any html or was is just that JS that you added. I can't say thank you enough, that was a big help and so quickly. thanks again and I have other skills I help others with and will continue to do so because of this full cycle. Thanks my man you ar awesome!

Comment: I didnt change the html, just a little part of js, but you can compare the code

Answer (score 0):

```
<select> 
<option selected="selected" value="first"/>
<option value="second"/>
</select>
```

I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Actually that is just the html version. I am looking for a way to write it in JS. The question is complex, sorry if I didn't word it correctly.

Comment: add an event listener to the option